# Manipulating matrices in Matlab using fmincon

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm currently trying to use fmincon in Matlab.

I can get it to operate correctly, but this falls over when i include manipulation of matrix elements which don't meet a condition.

As below

```
ub = 1.1;
lb = -1.2; 
aut = -0.25;

h = @(aut)eQ_Optim(aut);

  u = fmincon(h,aut, [], [], [], [], lb, ub)
```

The function i'm using is as follows

```
                function [Maxim]   = eQ_Optim(aut); 

                 Data = [-0.23183483,-0.003274012;
                         -0.289945477,0.000282334;
                         -0.483591973,0.006588649;
                         -0.257735378,0.000887691;
                         -0.286463622,-0.003235662;
                         -0.453939127,0.004358216;
                         -0.196363243,0.004186609;
                         -0.209783591,0.001715187];


   Data(Data(:,1)<aut,2)=0

                     MDOnx=Data(:,2)+1;
                     MD_Cumx=cumprod(MDOnx,1);
                     Maxim = MD_Cumx(end)*-1


 end
```

I'm trying to get fmincon to optimise the variable 'aut', such that it maximises the cumulative sum of the right hand column (Data(:,2)).

for reference, the output i'm receiving is

Initial point is a local minimum that satisfies the constraints.

Optimization completed because at the initial point, the objective function is non-decreasing 
in feasible directions to within the default value of the optimality tolerance, and 
constraints are satisfied to within the default value of the constraint tolerance.

u =
  -0.250000000000000

Which as you can see, is just my original guess being fed back to me.

I hope everything is clear. I've simplified everything as much as possible. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use fminbid with applicable intervals

% % % https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminbnd.html